# How to responsively embed Vimeo Videos into a Slick Slider?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, vimeo, slick.js

I have a slick.js slider with several videos and photos in them. I want all of them to have the same responsive height. With the images that’s easy since I can just give them `height: 60vh;`. I now struggle to responsively embed the videos that are hosted on vimeo, since the container div of the video needs to have a specified width to begin with. But since the videos can change and have different aspect ratios I don’t know the width.

I tried several ways including manually calculating the width of the container div by multiplying the height and the aspect ratio of the video (that I can obtain automatically by using the Vimeo API, but this is not part of the problem). But then the video will not resize when the browser window is changing height.

I have this jsfiddle setup:
https://jsfiddle.net/shy_seagull/3evy2tkp/23/

Is there a better way to do this than manually calculating the width of every video and changing the width of the container div with javascript?

Comment: I believe this would help: https://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/

Comment: @TheZ Thank you, I looked into the padding method, but it doesn’t solve the problem I have. I don’t need the height of the video to be relative to the width, but rather the other way around. I want to give the container a height of 60vh and adjust the width relative to that while maintaining the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: Hmm, video elements should already be locked into a proper aspect ratio unless you override the size. Looks like you can embed Vimeo with native html5 video tags if you have a premium or higher account on Vimeo:
https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-players-links

Assuming you don't and you're using an iframe... then I don't know what you can do, sorry.